# Sum the column value incrementally with the same ID column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble in querying in SQL Server 2008, I searched the internet but I found nothing or it is not giving me any ideas on how to do it.

Using Northwind database, I need to query the table OrderDetails and select OrderID and UnitPrice showing something like this,

```
OrderID   -    UnitPrice
------------------------
10248     -     14.00
10248     -     9.80
10248     -     34.80
10249     -     18.60
```

Result should be:

```
OrderID   -    UnitPrice
------------------------
10248     -     14.00
10248     -     23.80
10248     -     58.6
10249     -     18.60
```

Comment: I'm also curious on how this can be solved without using a temporary table to store the intermediate sums.

Comment: What DB? Oracle can do this easily, as can MSSQL 2012

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664142/cumulative-total-in-ms-sql-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check:

```
;with T as(
    select 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by OrderID order by OrderID) RNum
    from YourTable
)
select 
    *, 
    (select sum(UnitPrice) from T b where b.OrderID=a.OrderID and b.RNum<=a.RNum) CumTotal
From T a
```

Try in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b25ff/1)

Comment: WOW! it works!... thanks a lot @techdo . . . I am learning here... thanks, have a great day....

Answer (score -2):

Can refer following:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.unitprice,
       SUM(t2.unitprice) AS SUM
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN t t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id
GROUP BY t1.id,
         t1.unitprice
ORDER BY t1.id
```

**Demo:**

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b21de/2)

Comment: -1, incorrect. He wants to sequentially sum the rows with the **same** ID, not consecutive IDs.